# Next.js 13 render server component inside client component page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I build a simple landing page with next.js 13 with app router. I use `useRef` to create a "jump to section" effect by clicking menu from header to content of the page, but the section of the page fetch data from database directly with prisma (not using fetch to external api)

**page.tsx**

```js
"use client"
export default function Home() {
    const homeRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
    const aboutRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
    return (
      <>
         <Header sections={[homeRef, aboutRef]}/>
         <main className="main">
             <Home ref={homeRef}/>
             <About ref={aboutRef}/>
         </main>
      </>
    )
}
```

**about.tsx**

```js
export const About= forwardRef(async (props, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>) => {
    const about = await getAbout(); // fetching from database directly with prisma
    return (
        <section className="section" id="about" ref={ref}>
            <h1 className="section__title">About</h1>

            <p>{about.description}</p>
            <p>{about.last_updated_at}</p>
        </section>
    );
});
Expertise.displayName = 'About';
```

but I got error from prisma

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PrismaClient is unable to run in this browser environment, or has been bundled for the browser (running in `unknown`).
```

and nextjs itself

```
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components.
```

I read in docs and some references that Server components can import and render client components, but client components can't render the server components in it.

But I still need useRef and fetch data from database, how rendering strategy and compose the component that I can use to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

If getting "about" data at server is not a must, you can let your `About` component to be "client component".

Next, instead of calling `await getAbout()` directly, you can create an API route with `GET` method.

Finally, let your client `About` component handle remote data fetching (url will be the API route above) with library like Redux toolkit or tRPC or even build your own a simple solution for remote data fetching (with for basic states: init, fetching, success, failure).

Solution 2

If getting "about" data at server is a must:

- you can move `await getAbout()` back to `Home` page.
- remove `"use client"` to make `Home` page server component
- wrap the content of `Home` page to sub component and mark it `use client`
- the data you get will be passed to sub component as a prop (make sure you check requirements before passing data from server comp to client comp: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#passing-props-from-server-to-client-components-serialization)

Comment: in solution 1 initial page will not contain the about description and last updated information right (not SEO friendly), and the solution 2 I should lift the fetching outside the About component to make sure Prisma runs on server component?

Comment: yes, solution 1 is considering the full page as client components => not the best for SEO, while solution 2 takes advantange of hydration => your data will be fetched at server, you page will be pre-render at server => then send to client and hydrate.

Comment: i am not sure why you select `ref` as strategy but "jumping to section" can be achieved purely by `anchor` in `html` with `id` attribute. With that, no `useRef`, full page can be rendered statically at server => good for SEO.

Comment: Because I need to make the menu "active" in header when it's scrolled into the section and add some animation by calculate offset the section that's why I use `useRef`, any solution about that?

Comment: If you expect to use `userRef`, then follow solution 2.